# Can't find specific code when following iOS tutorial

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS programming and I'm reading this tutorial to get along http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1

There's a part where it tells me to open my MasterViewController.m and do this:

```
// Replace the return statement in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection with the following:
return _bugs.count;
```

And this:

```
// Replace tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath with the following
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyBasicCell"];
    ScaryBugDoc *bug = [self.bugs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = bug.data.title;
    cell.imageView.image = bug.thumbImage;
    return cell;
}
```

However, I can't find in this class a statement that says something like "tableView:numberOfRowsInSection" nor "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath".

Here is the code of my MasterViewController.m class:

```
#import "ScaryBugsMasterViewController.h"
#import "ScaryBugDoc.h"
#import "ScaryBugData.h"

@implementation ScaryBugsMasterViewController

@synthesize bugs = _bugs;


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.title = @"Scary Bugs"; 
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

@end
```

Did I do something wrong when creating the classes, maybe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UITableView needs these three methods to work.

(1) Specify the number of sections in the table

(2) Specify the number of rows per section in the table

(3) Create the UITableViewCell that will fill the rows of the table

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.bugs count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyBasicCell"];
    ScaryBugDoc *bug = [self.bugs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = bug.data.title;
    cell.imageView.image = bug.thumbImage;
    return cell;
}
```

Edit: Navigation to the bottom of the page and download the source code.  These method are implemented in the MasterViewController.

When you create a new class just subclass the UITableViewController and these method templates will automatically be in the class, you just have to implement them.

Comment: I see. But I don't understand why these method templates weren't already there. May I have missed a step?

Comment: @devGabriel if you create a Master-Detail Application those methods should be there and implement already with some code for you.  That is why the tutorial says replace, because you are just replacing the code inside the method.  The templates are just to give you a starting point, and help you out.

Comment: @devGabriel it is not a big deal though if those methods are not there, just add them yourself, and make sure you are view controller is a UITableViewController

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a UIViewController instead of an UITableViewController.  You will get the stubs for the table view delegate and data source methods if you use a UITableViewController.